# JPA type mappings issue

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, ejb, openjpa

I'm implementing simple Blog application using JEE technologies-EJB's, JPA persistence, MySQL DB, Apache TomEE server.
I am not sure how to annotate some of the types inside entities to be correctly mapped to appropriate mysql types.

For example, i have an entity named "Post" that has field "content", and here is how i have annotated it:

```
@Column(name = "post_content", columnDefinition = "TEXT", nullable = false)
private String content;
```

This field represents content of the blog post, and by its nature its length is not limited. (Blog post can be very long). I know that by default in JPA, String is being mapped to mysql varchar(255) type. This is the warning  i am getting;

```
WARN   [http-bio-8080-exec-10] openjpa.jdbc.Schema - Existing column "post_content" on table "post" is incompatible with the same column in the given schema definition. Existing column:
Full Name: post.post_content
Type: longvarchar
Size: 65535
Default: null
Not Null: true
Given column:
Full Name: post.post_content
Type: varchar
Size: 255
Default: null
Not Null: true
```

What is the proper way of annotating this kind of fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Column(name = "post_content", length=65535)
private String content;
```

The warning is complaining that the default for the column attribute is 255, yet the database column has a length of 655535. If you specify the proper length the warning will go away.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I forgot to put length parameter. Also,i was opinion that i need to explicitly specify one of mysql text types (varchar, longvarchar, text, blob) that i want string to map to. (Obviously persistence provider is handling type conversion).